# Cache response json with on route

Tags: 8, caching

Why doesn't this cache anything?

```
$cache = [
 '#cache' => [
   'tags' => [
     'test'
   ],
   'max-age' => -1
 ]
];
$response = new CacheableJsonResponse($data, 200);
$response->addCacheableDependency(CacheableMetadata::createFromRenderArray($cache));
```

Comment: How do you use this code? In which cache and under which circumstances this should get cached?

Comment: ! On route. The problem is that it always worked. In the last 2 projects created in the last week with drupal composer project it does not work anymore

Comment: Then it's very unlikely that there is something wrong with the code you've shown in the question.

Comment: ! Thz, I'm looking for something wrong with the environment